# Store 10 Latest Rows from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm quite new to MySQL, so don't judge! Anyhow, what I'm trying to do is store the 10 newest rows in a MySQL database into a PHP array. My variable $news contains the MySQL data I got from running the fetch_news() query (which I told only to grab content that has a column called type with the value "news" in it). However, I've been unable to do this successfully.

If you guys could offer some help, or guidance, it'd be much appreciated as I have been stuck on on this for quite some time now!

[image: LAYOUT OF MY TABLE IN MYSQL]

Comment: What is the layout of the table?

Comment: Okay, I've attached a picture of my database now. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT *
          FROM `table_name`
          WHERE `type`="news"
          ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
          LIMIT 10';
$query = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you please be able to explain the code a little though? I like to know exactly what I'm doing. Also, what is the $link variable for?

Comment: @user3020461 manual will do it better than me: http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: You should sort on `article_timestamp` rather than on `article_id` since you don't know that articles are always inserted in time order (e.g. an old article might be inserted post-facto).

Comment: @fearless_fool fair enoughб but it depends on what OP meant by "latest rows".

Comment: Yes, but comments by user3020461 suggest that article_timestamp is what's intended ("Is the article_timestamp not helpful at all in this case?").

Answer (score 0):

While your "type" column tells you if the row is a news item or not, it doesn't tell you anything about when it was added to the table.
You need to use some other column as well, either some sort of incremental counter (like the "article_id" might be), or a time stamp when the item was added to your table (this is probably the "article_timestamp" in your case).

With one of those you can sort the results the way you want.
When you have sorted your results, you need to limit them to just the 10 you want.

You can find more information about ORDER BY and LIMIT in the [Official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Is the article_timestamp not helpful at all in this case?

Comment: It probably is, so I've edited my reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newest_ten = array();
$command = "select * from table_name order by date DESC limit 10";
$result = $db->query($command);
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $newest_ten[] = $data;
}
```

The command is getting all columns from the table table_name, putting them in order based on their date (so newest to oldest), and then only giving you the first ten of those.

The while loop goes through the results and adds them to an array.

Comment: @Hast 's command uses the same logic, if you don't want to read the manual.